# Microsoft Booking with Salesforce APIs

Tags: asp.net-core, salesforce

Can I integrate Microsoft Bookings to my ASP.NET core MVC app using Salesforce APIs? Could not find related Salesforce APIs for MS Bookings in their documentation

Comment: This question should be more descriptive.

Comment: This is a very common issue most of the developers face

Answer (score 0):

> Can I integrate Microsoft Bookings to my ASP.NET core MVC app using
> Salesforce APIs?

Not found the related article about using the Salesforce API to integrate Microsoft Booking to Asp.net core MVC APP.

But, Microsoft Bookings provide a way for you to embed your Bookings calendar in your site via an iFrame. Link embedding code is located in the Bookings page tab within the Bookings app (login Booking, select Booking page -> click Embed on the top, then it will show HTML and Iframe code).

Check the following screenshot:

[image]

Reference:[Embed Booking site into my website](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/embed-booking-site-into-my-website/ce4e987f-6ba8-457f-aae2-492b8d1ee393)

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that way earlier. But we cannot pre-fill booking form data and identify whether booking is successfull using JS as we cannot get any element inside that form using JS. I would really appreciate if there is a way to catch element inside the booking form using js.